# What effect does /usr/bin/env have?

Tags: shell, shebang

What's the difference between `#! /usr/bin/env ruby` and `#! ruby`?

(I found many other questions discussing the difference between `#! /usr/bin/env ruby` and `#! /usr/bin/ruby`, but that's not my question.)

Comment: `#! ruby` must be in your path. So `#! ruby` and `#!/usr/bin/ruby` are probably the same thing, depending on your path.

Comment: actually i just did a test as root where `#! ruby` resulted in "ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"… so for some reason ruby isn't naturally in the root environment, but /usr/bin/env can find it. but i thought /user/bin/env was supposed to use the user's path anyway...

Comment: Hmm actually it looks like `#! ruby` must be a special case, since `#! python` won't work since *the interpreter must be a valid pathname for an executable* - see [Additional information on the shebang; why doesn't #!python work?](http://askubuntu.com/a/716281/272194)

Comment: @JohnBachir, `#! ruby` failing has nothing to do with whether ruby is in root's PATH. There's no PATH lookup done in evaluating a shebang at all.

Comment: ...at least, not when shebang evaluation is done *by the kernel*. I have seen scenarios where a shell will try to take that into its own hands, but if you try to execute a script without a shell interpreter involved (for instance, with `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec ./somescript {} +`), then you guarantee that the behavior you're seeing is that of the kernel, thus avoiding confounding factors.

Comment: Indirectly related: [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#! ruby
```

...is not guaranteed to work on UNIXlike systems (and *does not* work on any I personally know of) at all; a valid shebang must have a *fully qualified* path. It may suffice to tell your editor which programming language you're using, but that doesn't mean that the kernel will successfully use it to select an interpreter with which to run a program.

The kernel's `execve` syscall doesn't do PATH lookups -- that's added by C-standard-library wrappers such as `execlp` and `execvp`, but parsing shebangs is done directly by the kernel, so your C-library nicities don't happen there.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

...uses the PATH to look up the location of the `ruby` executable. Because the path to the `env` executable is fully specified, this is a valid shebang line (which `#! ruby` is not).

---

`env` has other purposes as well -- you can run, for instance, `env -i someprog` to run `someprog` with a completely empty environment, or `env FOO=bar someprog` to run `someprog` with the environment variable `FOO` set to the value `bar` (which `FOO=bar someprog` would also do if running through a shell, but the `env` approach also works with no shell involved).

However, the relevant use case in this context is forcing a PATH lookup.